# Mobilefirst 8.0 Error IOS PUSH Notifications. Failed to load netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64, netty_tcnative_ppc_64, netty_tcnative

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have updated Mobilefirst Platform Foundations 8.0 to the last fix available right now (8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF202011111304) After applying the fix, we didn't have any problem, however when we tried to send an IOS push notification we got this error:

> [1/22/21 10:05:36:058 CST] 00000484 Mediator      E
> com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.Mediator submitNotification
> FPWSE1081E: Failure sending notification. See the server log file for
> more details.
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library   at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.ensureAvailability(OpenSsl.java:474)     at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:196)
> at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:185)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslContext.(OpenSslContext.java:34)
> at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslClientContext.(OpenSslClientContext.java:189)
> at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:827)
> at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:576)
> at
> com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.nettyapns.NettyApplicationConnection.setService(NettyApplicationConnection.java:433)
> at
> com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.nettyapns.NettyApplicationConnection.sendNotification(NettyApplicationConnection.java:137)
> at
> com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:166)
> at
> com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.Mediator$2.run(Mediator.java:105)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given
> libraries: [netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64, netty_tcnative_ppc_64,
> netty_tcnative]   at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:104)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:581)  at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.(OpenSsl.java:133)   at
> com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.nettyapns.NettyApplicationConnection.setService(NettyApplicationConnection.java:419)
> ... 8 more  Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not
> load a native library: netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64      at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
> ... 11 more     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64.a        at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:173)
> ... 12 more         Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)            at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462)          at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:584)            at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:349)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
> ... 12 more             Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:584)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:369)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:361)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:339)
> ... 13 more     Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_ppc_64      at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
> ... 11 more     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_ppc_64.a        at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:173)
> ... 12 more         Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> netty_tcnative_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)            at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462)          at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:584)            at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:349)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
> ... 12 more             Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> netty_tcnative_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:584)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:369)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:361)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:339)
> ... 13 more     Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative         at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
> ... 11 more     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative.a       at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:173)
> ... 12 more         Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> netty_tcnative (Not found in java.library.path)           at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462)          at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:584)            at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:349)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
> ... 12 more             Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> netty_tcnative (Not found in java.library.path)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:584)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:369)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:361)
> at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:339)
> ... 13 more

According to the error, it looks like there is a missing library. Searching inside of the war I found out, that there are not libraries for aix.

[image: Libraries]

There is someone out there with the same problem, or should I open a case with IBM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a case with IBM so we can track it and provide timely update/solution.
We are aware of the issue and working on it. Till then please use Legacy protocol to send APNS notifications.

To switch to Legacy protocol you need to set below JNDI to false

`<jndiEntry jndiName="imfpush/mfp.push.apns.http2.enabled" value= '"false"'/>`

Thanks.

Comment: I applied the property and it solved the problem. Thanks